# Returning on a recursive function in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, recursion, return

I'm developing a function to parse 2 xml files. It compares them node by node and then if the nodes are different, the function should return one of them. But it isn't returning anything.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file1.xml");
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("file2.xml");

$result = parseNode($xml, $xml2);
print_r($result);
echo $result;

function parseNode($node1, $node2) {

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($node1->children()); $i++) {

        $child1 = $node1->children();
        $child2 = $node2->children();

        if ($child1[$i]->getName() != $child2[$i]->getName()) {
            return $child1[$i];
        } else {
            parseNode($child1[$i], $child2[$i]);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do it with a simple conditional statement...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("file1.xml");
$xml2 = simplexml_load_file("file2.xml");

$result = parseNode($xml, $xml2);
print_r($result);
echo $result;

function parseNode($node1, $node2) {
    $child1 = $node1->children();
    $child2 = $node2->children();
    $numChildren = count($child1);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numChildren; $i++) {
        if ($child1[$i]->getName() != $child2[$i]->getName()) {
            return $child1[$i];
        } else {
            $test = parseNode($child1[$i], $child2[$i]);
            if ($test) return $test;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
       return parseNode($child1[$i], $child2[$i]);
```

Comment: print_r($result) and echo $result still print nothing.

Comment: I had a related problem.  The recursion would not return anything on array keys that were deeper than the root level.  Added return and it worked.  Thanks @hwlau

Answer (score 1):

You could also loop over the XML structures using recursive iterators to simplify your `parseNodes()` function.

```
$xml  = simplexml_load_string("<root><foo/><bar><baz/></bar></root>", "SimpleXMLIterator");
$xml2 = simplexml_load_string("<root><foo/><bar><baz/></bar><bat/></root>", "SimpleXMLIterator");

$result = parseNode($xml, $xml2);
echo $result;

function parseNode($a, $b) {
    $mit = new MultipleIterator(MultipleIterator::MIT_NEED_ANY|MultipleIterator::MIT_KEYS_NUMERIC);
    $mit->attachIterator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($a, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST));
    $mit->attachIterator(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($b, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST));

    foreach ($mit as $node) {
        // One has more nodes than another!
        if (  ! isset($node[0], $node[1])) {
            return 'Curse your sudden but inevitable betrayal!';
        }
        // Nodes have different names
        if ($node[0]->getName() !== $node[1]->getName()) {
            return $node[0];
        }
    }

    // No differences in names and order
    return FALSE;
}
```

Setting up the `MultipleIterator` is pretty verbose (mostly due to the über-long class names) but the logic is darned simple.

Answer (score 0):

There's no `return` in the recursive call. Hence, no result.

**EDIT** Do not up-vote this. *ircmaxell* is right. I have removed the exception part of my answer.

Comment: -1 for abuse of Exceptions.  It's not an exceptional circumstance, so there's no reason for all the overhead that's associated with exceptions...

Comment: What overhead would that be? And where is there an "abuse"? Is it not a flow control statement?

Comment: print_r($result) and echo $result still print nothing.

Comment: The full backtrace that's generated.  Exceptions are not cheap.  And they should not be abused for non-exceptional circumstances.  I highly suggest giving [Code Complete 2](http://www.amazon.com/Code-Complete-Practical-Handbook-Construction/dp/0735619670) a read...

Comment: Actually it does. But I need the function to return one of the nodes.